# Identify only non duplicated rows

Tags: r, unique, rows, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with many duplicated rows, and I would like to isolate only **non duplicated values**. 
my df looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame("group" = c("A", "A", "A","A","A","B","B","B"), 
                    "id" = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id1", "id2","id1","id2","id1"), 
                    "Val" = c(10,10,10,10,10,12,12,12))
```

What I would like to extract are only the rows that do not have a duplicate. i.e. my final dataset should look like this

```
final <- data.frame("group" = c("A","B"), 
                 "id" = c("id3","id2"), 
                 "Val" = c(10,12))
```

Note I am not interested in finding unique values, but rather non duplicated ones. 
I know how to find unique values, for instance `df %>% distinct()` does the job. it is individuating non-duplicated rows that I am struggling with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one option.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter(!(duplicated(id)|duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE)))
```

---

Or with `dplyr` alone

```
df %>% 
     group_by_all %>%
     filter(n() ==1)
```

---

Or in the newer version of `dplyr` (suggested by @Pål Bjartan)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(across(everything())) %>% 
  filter(n() ==1)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df[!(duplicated(df[1:2])|duplicated(df[1:2], fromLast = TRUE)),]
```

Comment: @d.b.  Yes, I thought the OP wanted only selected number of columns as grouping

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Most helpful. =) Regarding your `dplyr` solution, scoped verbs (`_if`, `_at`, `_all`) have been superceded by `across()` in an existing verb. I suggest you update your solution to reflect this: `df %>% group_by(across(everything())) %>% filter(n() ==1)`